# Something went wrong when processing the logo

Tags: config, upload

I've just installed Craft on a new Laravel Homestead environment and all seems to be running fine, with the exception of being able to upload a logo in the General settings.

The logo uploads and displays in the popup for cropping, but when I save it, I get this error flashed up:

> Something went wrong when processing the logo.

I've checked the permissions and everything seems fine - the storage dir is set to 777 on my local box just to be doubly sure and I can see Craft is creating files and folders in there.

The $imagePath variable in the RebrandController::RebrandController() method is as follows:

> /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/craft/storage/runtime/temp/uploads/Rally-Digital-Logo.png&d=1420216657

Aside from permissions, what could cause this?

Comment: Check your `craft\storage\runtime\logs` files and search for `[error]` to get the underlying error message.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I can see the following:
2015/01/02 19:23:26 [error] [application] Could not delete the file /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/craft/storage/runtime/temp/uploads/Rally-Digital-Logo.png&d=1420226600 because the file does not exist.
in /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/craft/app/helpers/IOHelper.php (1313)
in /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/craft/app/controllers/RebrandController.php (134)
in /home/vagrant/sites/craft-base/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (754). The file must exist though surely, as it was shown in the crop view?

Comment: Yeah, and that shouldn't be a fatal error, too.  Do you have a `phperrors.log` file in that folder?

Comment: Nope - I cleared out the logs dir and that's all there is.

Comment: Hrm... can you enable devMode, reproduce the issue, zip up your logs folder and send it over to support@buildwithcraft.com?  I'll update here with any results.

Comment: I've sent to you via the widget on the admin panel. Let me know if you haven't got them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the URL of the image.

The RebrandController class removes '?' querystrings from the URL but in my case I had a '&'. Removing that solved the issue and Brad has confirmed this fix has been rolled into the next release.